# Rails Migrations Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a weird issue that started yesterday afternoon. I'm learning Rails and I have been working on an app for a few weeks now. Yesterday afternoon, after I ran `rake db:migrate:reset`, I was returned to the command prompt without any of the table creation details that I normally see. When I look in the database, no tables were added from my migrations. When I look in my development.log I see:

```
No secret token environment variable set
Unable to get OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN, using default
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Is the secret token required to run migration? I don't recall changing anything configuration wise from the time it last worked and the time this error started.

I'm not sure if it matters but my secrets.yml looks like this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: bff55d0fe1d657a6cc20d1408545052f3bacc91b9067f2c34a9d7095f12cd9a4703064635d4b2b895c0c0c3468a2ba2b331ab069ad86859200c361c3c65728p7

test:
  secret_key_base: af4bc244f775d2872ace944ea761f4f0793dbc33ed989abe04f1e95581fdf2cac4ca5e8226845fb23ce8dfcd775848a533c91dbfb02b5734f3af3c8eee16d780

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I am hosting my "production" version of this app on OpenShift. Did I perhaps misconfigure something when I pulled from that repository?

Comment: Where are you running `rake db:migrate:reset` command? In your production environment?

Comment: I'm running it from my development environment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention. The error is saying `OPENSHIFT`. Did you host or wrote your app to work on OpenShift? Did you configure their gem `rhs`? Look into your initializers. Most probably one of those is looking for `OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Uzbekjon. I originally cloned the app from the OpenShift Rails Quickstart and it has been working fine until yesterday. I found that if I log in to postgres and drop/recreate the database I can run rake db:migrate and the migrations run, but if I make any updates or changes, the migrations won't run a second time and I have to log in, drop/recreate the database and then run the migrations.

Comment: Are you using git? If yes, run this command `git grep OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN`. This should help you identify where it is being used/required.